# Wireshark or one associated with it is already running

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to uninstall Wireshark. I closed all wireshark instances. but still it is giving error as Wireshark or one associated with it is already running. How to uninstall it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing which OS you're running, but generally you should open up your task manager and see if there are any Wireshark or Tshark or Dumpcap processes still running that would cause this. Optionally also try rebooting...

Comment: Dumpcap process was running. Thanks saved my lots of time.

Comment: In my case it seemed to have been "USBPcapCMD.exe".

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively you can also use the Windows cmd command

```
tasklist | findstr -i "cap"
```

And then check for any of the **wireshark** related component, something like *usbcap*, *dumpcap* and if you find one, use the below command to kill it.

```
taskkill -f /PID xxxx
```

Where *xxxx* is the process ID of the output of the first command.